# After insert, select count(1) from ReplicatedMergeTree engine table at once, get difference result for many times

Tags: clickhouse

The situation is that: I insert some data into `ReplicatedMergeTree` engine table, and I do this query `select count(1) from table` at once, and I get different results. As I know, this is caused by the Replicated mechanism, It will spend some time for Replicated shard copying data, so if the query routes to Replicated shard and will respond different result.

How can I avoid this problem if I want to use the data I insert at once?

Comment: Are you reading from Distributed table?

Comment: yes, I read from distributed table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading from Distributed table you can play with the next settings:

- *insert_quorum* setting for **INSERT** queries. For example, for 3 replicas you specify `insert_quorum = 3`, so client will wait until data is replicates across all 3 replicas. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-insert_quorum
- *select_sequential_consistency*. Setting for **SELECT** queries. Select will include the data written with *insert_quorum*. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-select_sequential_consistency

Comment: @zhang I'm glad to help. If it is solving your issue, would you mind marking this answer as accepted? It's by clicking on the check mark next below the points of the answer. Thanks ;-)